# Texture Tiling and Texture Coordinates in Unreal Engine

Tags: textures, models

I've just started to learn how to develop games and everything is new for me now.

I don't know where to start and I decided to start with Textures and there is something it is difficult to understand for me: `Texture Tiling`.

I'm not an English speaker and I have searched the meaning of tile and tiling on my own language (Spanish) and I think tile is a way to say repeat the texture across the model instead of stretching it.

I have found [PolyCount Wiki](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Texturing) and this is how they explain tiling:

> Textures can be repeated across a model, by Tiling the
>   TextureCoordinates.

My problem here is that I don't understand the meaning of `Tiling`. Can I replace Tiling with Repeating without changing the meaning of the sentence?

I have another question is about `Texture Coordinates`. On [PolyCount Wiki](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/TextureCoordinates) they say that:

> Texture coordinates are measured in a scale of 0.0 to 1.0, with 0.0
>   and 1.0 at opposite sides of the texture. When a model has a UV
>   distance greater than 1 (for example, UV goes from -1 to 2) then the
>   texture will tile across the model.

How can I know if I model has a UV distance greater that 1?

By the way, I'm using Unreal Engine, and on its [Texture Coordinate element](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference/Coordinates/#texturecoordinate) I don't understand the meaning of amount of tiling in their UTiling and VTiling properties.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care about checking if the UV coordinates are bigger than 1. Every Graphics API (D3D and OpenGL) handles such UV coordinates by taking the modulo 1 of them.

Tiling in graphics world means almost the same thing as in the real world. You take a small piece of texfure abd your repeat it over and over until it fills the whole surface.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Unreal Engine and I don't understand the usage of UTiling and VTiling, https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference/Coordinates/#texturecoordinate. What does "amount of tiling" means?

Comment: UTiling: tile on the U axis; VTiling: tile on the V axis. Amount of tiling means how much it should be repeated